# Why does procmail send a copy of an inbound message to sender if it encounters an exit code?

Tags: email, exit, procmail

I have a very simple procmail process that takes an inbound email and redirects it to a script:

```
LOGFILE=/home/foo/procmail-log
VERBOSE=yes
MAILDIR=/var/spool/mail/foo
DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/foo
SHELL=/bin/sh

:0
! `/home/foo/scripts/blah/blah.sh`
```

The shell script has a condition that greps a file for a sender's email address and if it finds it, it exits:

```
grep i "$SENDER" /home/foo/scripts/blah/blah2.txt

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

When this happens, I want procmail to just give up / discard the message.

Interestingly enough though, if this triggers, procmail taking the value I just grepped and trying to send an email to it.

In the procmail log, I see:

```
procmail: Notified comsat: "foo@:/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi sender@foodomain.com sender@foodomain.com"
From sender@foodomain.com  Thu Feb  6 22:31:47 2014
 Subject: Test
  Folder: /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi sender@foodomain.com sender     3165
procmail: Executing "/usr/sbin/sendmail,-oi,sender@foodomain.com,sender@foodomain.com"
```

Why is it doing this?  Is there any way I can configure procmail to not do this? I just want it to give up and drop the prior email it was processing.  I've tried different exit codes (0, 1, 77) but procmail always does the same thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Could you explain what action Procmail should be taking, in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procmail makes great efforts to assure that mail is not lost even if delivery fails.  According to `man procmail`, email will be bounced back to sender as a last resort:

> ```
>    ORGMAIL     Usually  the system mailbox (ORiGinal MAIL‐
>                box).  If, for some  obscure  reason  (like
>                `filesystem  full')  the  mail could not be
>                delivered, then this mailbox  will  be  the
>                last resort.  If procmail fails to save the
>                mail in here (deep, deep trouble :-),  then
>                the mail will bounce back to the sender
> ```

There is, however, an environment variable that can be set to allow mail to be discarded rather than bounced:

> ```
>    DELIVERED   If set to `yes' procmail will  pretend  (to
>                the  mail  agent)  the mail has been deliv‐
>                ered.  If mail cannot  be  delivered  after
>                having  met this assignment (set to `yes'),
>                the mail will be lost (i.e.,  it  will  not
>                bounce).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your action:

```
:0
! `script`
```

The meaning of the backticks is "use the output of `script` as a string here".  So if your script outputs `foo@example.com` then the recipe will effectively be equivalent to

```
:0
! foo@example.com
```

which means to forward the message to `foo@example.com`.  The behavior you describe should thus not be surprising at all; Procmail is doing precisely what you are telling it to do.

If you just want to discard the message altogether if your script returns success, you can try this trick:

```
:0W
| script
```

This is basically the same as the [`formail -D` example for suppressing duplicates](http://partmaps.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#formail-dupe); if the script returns a success exit status, the message is considered delivered; but since the script doesn't actually deliver it anywhere, it is actually lost.  (You will obviously need to change the logic of your script so that its exit code is the inverse of what it is now.)

In case you want the syntax sorted out for you, here is a more general attempt at doing what you seem to think you were doing:

```
:0
? script
! somewhere
```

which will forward to `somewhere` if the exit code of `script` is zero (as in success); or possibly

```
# Capture the output from script in WHERE
WHERE=`script`
# Also capture its exit code
ERR=$?

# Forward to $WHERE if $ERR is zero
:0
* ERR ?? ^^0^^
! $WHERE
```

(Several arcane details of uncommon Procmail syntax are present here.  The `??` operand examines the value of the named variable; the `^^` anchor matches beginning / end of input string.)

If your script is no more complex than that, you might as well inline it.  (Notice the syntax fix with a dash before the `i` option, and the inversion of the exit status with `!`):

```
:0
* ! ? grep -i "$SENDER" /home/foo/scripts/blah/blah2.txt
! somewhere
```